# Saving kinect v2 frames in an array

Tags: arrays, kinect, capture

I am trying to develop a software based on Kinect v2 and I need to keep the capturedframes in an array. I have a problem and I dont have any idea about it as follow.

The captured frames are processed by my processing class and the processed writable bitmap will be called as the source of the image box in my ui window which works perfectly and I have a realtime frames in my ui. 
for example:

```
/// Color
_ProcessingInstance.ProcessColor(colorFrame);
ImageBoxRGB.Source = _ProcessingInstance.colorBitmap;
```

but when I want to assign this to an element of an array, all of the elements in array will be identical as the first frame!! I should mention that, this action is in the reading event which above action is there.
the code:

```
ColorFrames_Array[CapturingFrameCounter] = _ProcessingInstance.colorBitmap;
```

the equal check in intermediate window:

```
ColorFrames_Array[0].Equals(ColorFrames_Array[1])
true
ColorFrames_Array[0].Equals(ColorFrames_Array[2])
true
```

Please give me some hints about this problem. Any idea?

Comment: This happens probably because you are not creating a new `_ProcessingInstance`, so all the elements refer to one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Yar

You are right and when I create a new instance, frames are saved correctly.
But my code was based on the Microsoft example and problem is that creating new instances makes the memory leakage because writablebitmap is not disposable.

similar problem is discussed in the following link which the frames are frizzed to the first frame and this is from the intrinsic properties of writeablebitmap:

http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it

Therefore i use a strategy similar to the above solution and try to get a copy instead of the original bitmap frame. In this scenario, I have create a new writeblebitmap for each element of ColorFrames_Array[] at initialization step.

```
ColorFrames_Array = new riteableBitmap[MaximumFramesNumbers_Capturing];
            for (int i=0; i < MaximumFramesNumbers_Capturing; ++i)
            {
                ColorFrames_Array[i] = new WriteableBitmap(color_width, color_height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
            }
```

and finally, use clone method to copy the bitmap frames to array elements.

```
ColorFrames_ArrayBuffer[CapturingFrameCounter] = _ProcessingInstance.colorBitmap.Clone();
```

While above solution works, but it has a huge memory leakage!!. 
Therefore I use Array and .copypixel methods (of writeablebitmap) to copy the pixels of the frame to array and hold it (while the corresponding writeablebitmap will be disposed correctly without leakage).

```
public Array[] ColorPixels_Array;
```

---

```
for (int i=0; i< MaximumFramesNumbers_Capturing; ++i)
            {
ColorPixels_Array[i]=new int[color_Width * color_Height];
        }
```

---

```
colorBitmap.CopyPixels(ColorPixels_Array[Counter_CapturingFrame], color_Width * 4, 0);
```

---

Finally, when we want to save the arrays of pixels, we need to convert them new writeablebitmap instances and write them on hard.

```
wb = new WriteableBitmap(color_Width, color_Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
wb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, color_Width, color_Height)
                                , Ar_Px,
                                color_Width * 4, 0);
```